# Function call not working in Javascript code for Firefox extension when using the Google box

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, dom-events

I've written some code which works fine except that for an unknown reason a function does not work (the function is not called as if not existing).

The aim of my code is to detect if I'm using Google search engine. It works this way : when a user puts a keyword on the Google search field and types enter or clicks on "Search" the url changes and my code detects it and displays a Javascript alert with the URL of the page and another with the text "It matches".

But the problem is that when I type the keyword directly in the Google box it doesn't work anymore.

My code:

```
    function displayUrl(url)
    { 
       if(url[0].match(/^http:\/\/www\.google\.fr/))
       {
           alert('It matches');
       }
    }

    function getUrlVars(href)
    {
       var vars = [], hash;
       var hashes = href.slice(href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
       for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
       {
           hash = hashes[i].split('=');
           vars.push(hash[0]);
           vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
       }
       displayUrl(vars);
    }

    var myExt_urlBarListener = {
     QueryInterface: function(aIID)
     {
       if (aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener) ||
           aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsWeakReference) ||
           aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupports))
         return this;
       throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
    },

    onLocationChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aURI)
    {
       myExtension.processNewURL(aURI);
    },

    onStateChange: function(a, b, c, d) {},
    onProgressChange: function(a, b, c, d, e, f) {},
    onStatusChange: function(a, b, c, d) {},
    onSecurityChange: function(a, b, c) {}
    };

    var myExtension = {
     oldURL: null,

     init: function() {
        // Listen for webpage loads
        gBrowser.addProgressListener(myExt_urlBarListener,
            Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_LOCATION);
     },

     uninit: function() {
       gBrowser.removeProgressListener(myExt_urlBarListener);
     },

     processNewURL: function(aURI) {
        if (aURI.spec == this.oldURL)
          return;

       // now we know the url is new...
       alert(aURI.spec);
       /* 
       the following function call doesn't work
       when I type the keyword in the Google box instead of using the Google
       traditionnal search field          
       */
       getUrlVars(aURI.spec);
       this.oldURL = aURI.spec;

     }
  };

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {myExtension.init()}, false);
  window.addEventListener("unload", function() {myExtension.uninit()}, false);
```

Comment: "Does not work" ***how***? What do you expect, and what is it doing instead? What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: @TJ Crowder What I meant by function call not working is that nothing appears (as if the function call did not exist). I'm currently exploring the error console.

Answer (score 1):

This should work on a adress like

```
http://domain.com/page.php?http://www.google.fr=something
```

Inside displayUrl you're checking if the key of the first GET-parameter of the url provided to getUrlVars() matches **http://www.google.fr** . I guess that's not what you want^^

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thanks for your answer. My problem has evolved and I've changed my post accordingly.

Comment: @Bruno: Don't do this. If you have a new question - create a new question and credit the people who answered the previous one. Your code is still wrong, the issue mentioned by Dr.Molle hasn't been addressed.

Comment: @Wladimir Palant I don't understand where is the problem with my regex : I've used it and it worked great so far.

Comment: @Bruno: There is no problem with "the regex" - but with the code in your question `url[0]` in `displayUrl()` will be the name of the first parameter, not the URL.

Comment: @Bruno: Probably because the code you are testing and the code you gave us aren't the same?

Comment: @Wladimir Palant I'm going to check :-) (but I don't think so)

Comment: @Wladimir Palant Verification done : I've only put getUrlVars(aURI.spec) before this.oldURL = aURI.spec. The rest of the code hasn't changed.